# Check CTL specification in SMV

Tags: model-checking, ctl, nusmv

When I try to check "EG (!s11included & !s10included)" in SMV, it is reported false and gives a counter example as follows, which I think on the contrary it support this CTL specification. Is there something wrong with my CTL specification?

```
-- specification EG (!s11included & !s10included)  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
  -> State: 9.1 <-
    s00included = TRUE
    s01included = TRUE
    s10included = FALSE
    s11included = FALSE
```

Comment: Please, if you can, let us see your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

No, there isn't anything wrong with your **CTL** specification: what you observe is normal and entirely depends on your model specification.

The tool prints a **counter-example** up to the first state *(included)* violating a given property. Although it appears a bit arbitrary to a human operator since the **reason** for a property violation can get sometimes hidden from the execution trace itself, this design choice makes perfect sense from the point of view of **CTL** model checking. *The important thing to note is that the result can be trusted and, more importantly, double-checked by running a simulation.*

---

**EXAMPLE:**

I invite you to look at the following example.

```sh
MODULE main
VAR a : boolean;
VAR b : boolean;

ASSIGN
next(a) := case
    a = FALSE : { TRUE };
    TRUE      : { TRUE, FALSE };
  esac;

next(b) := case
    b = FALSE : { TRUE };
    TRUE      : { TRUE, FALSE };
  esac;

CTLSPEC EG (!a & !b);
```

In this model, whenever `a` (resp. `b`) is `FALSE` we deterministically set it to `TRUE`, otherwise we allow it to change arbitrarily.

If we check the **CTL** property, which is exactly the same as yours, we obtain the following **counter-example**:

```sh
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i test.smv ; go; check_property
-- specification EG (!a & !b)  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
-> State: 1.1 <-
  a = FALSE
  b = FALSE
```

As you can see, the **counter-example** matches yours *100%*. What is going on?

Well, basically **NuSMV** conservatively prints the fewest number of states necessary in order to reach a state in which the property is violated. In this case, the **initial-state** of the execution trace already violates the property, because the **next, deterministic, transition** leads to a state in which either `a` or `b` are `TRUE` *(in this specific case, both)*:

```sh
NuSMV > pick_state -s 1.1
NuSMV > simulate -iv -k 2
********  Simulation Starting From State 3.1   ********

***************  AVAILABLE STATES  *************

================= State =================
0) -------------------------
  a = TRUE
  b = TRUE


There's only one available state. Press Return to Proceed.

Chosen state is: 0

***************  AVAILABLE STATES  *************

================= State =================
0) -------------------------
  a = TRUE
  b = TRUE


================= State =================
1) -------------------------
  b = FALSE


================= State =================
2) -------------------------
  a = FALSE
  b = TRUE


================= State =================
3) -------------------------
  b = FALSE


Choose a state from the above (0-3): ^C
```

My conjecture is that your **model** has a similar behaviour, and that is the reason why you obtain the same result.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But I found that even if I add the INIT constraint "INIT a = FALSE; INIT b = FALSE". The CTLSPEC in your example "EG (!a & !b)" is still evaluated as FALSE. Then I change the CTLSPEC to "!AG (a|b)", which  should be equivalent. The result is evaluated as true. Therefore, I suspect that NuSMV (NuXMV) does not support EG in CTLSPEC.

Comment: @YulinZhang it is **correct** for `EG (!a & !b)` to be `TRUE` even with `INIT a = FALSE & b = FALSE`, because there is **only** one  **next state**  and it is equal to `a = TRUE & b = TRUE`, which violates `!a & !b` and therefore there is **no execution-path** starting at the **initial state** `!a & !b` such that `!a & !b` holds forever. The equivalent formula to `EG (!a & !b)` is `! AF (a | b)`.

Comment: You are right. I made some mistakes in using de morgan's law. Thank you.